# Meaning of "Do not expect troubles as they have a tendency not to disappoint"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In Think and Grow Rich Chapter 16, the author said,

> Do not expect troubles as they have a tendency not to disappoint.

Why do troubles "have a tendency *not* to disappoint"? Don't they "have a tendency to disappoint"?

And why would anyone expect troubles?

Comment: Possibly it says that 'they have a tendency not to disappoint', but does it mean that we need not expect troubles...

Comment: The first part means do not worry needlessly (“expect”) about problems that may or not happen in the future. Remember we live in the **now**, not in the future or past.

Comment: The second part means that worrying or preparing about problems/troubles can make them more likely to occur. They won’t “disappoint” ie they won’t let you down - they will arrive as anticipated.

Comment: Thanks I see it now. "Disappoint" here refers to whether the trouble comes as expected, not the actual effect of the trouble.

Comment: @Yang yes that’s it

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase in general, it's an expression that talks about a *self-fulfilling prophecy*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-fulfilling_prophecy):

> **Self-fulfilling prophecy** refers to the socio-psychological phenomenon of someone "predicting" or expecting something, and this “prediction” or expectation comes true simply because one believes it will, and their resulting behaviors align to fulfil those beliefs. This suggests peoples' beliefs influence their actions. The principle behind this phenomenon is people create consequences regarding people or events, based on their previous knowledge toward that specific subject. Additionally, self-fulfilling prophecy is applicable to negative and positive outcomes.

While it applies to both positive and negative thoughts, the expression is more commonly understood when it comes to negative thoughts.

In short, the more you *believe* you will fail (or bad things will happen) the more likely it is that you'll inadvertently sabotage yourself (if only unconsciously), and you actually *will* fail. (So, your prediction will not fail—or disappoint—you in its accuracy.)

People can have a habit of predicting trouble if they see things (or focus only on things) that happen to them in a negative light. They talk about all the bad things that have happened to them, and then say that because of that they don't expect anything different in the future.

The opposite can also be true, but it's often not as apparent.